# Executor Framework examples

Tags: java, future, executorservice, completable-future

i am a beginner in using Executor framework world. Please suggest some link or book where i can find lots of code examples having usage of executor framework from easy to complex problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concurrent programming is a vast topic and you will need to study a lot ;) I can only suggest the book "[Concurrent Programming in Java](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/B004V9OA84/)" as a starting point, it will give you the necessary grounds about the topic. And yes, it will also explain you how executors work.

Comment: I am already studying that, but sample code for problems where i can debug them and understand them. Helps to gain knowledge fast.